# trouble with Oracle Application Express

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am currently using Oracle Application Express to design a demo application cause I am new to it.
The problem that I have is the following
create a work space that works 100%
create an application with pages and data in the application
when I work on a page that I have made in the application I can create it and insert info but when I want to save it then says session has expired but I have not left it alone I am still in the application
can anyone help me with it

Comment: Which Apex version is it? Where is it installed (on your own PC? Elsewhere?). Can you check what are maximum session length and session idle time properties set to?

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this a few times while developing applications that do not require any authentication. If you are on a page that is "public" (does not require authentication) and try to launch a modal window that requires authentication, you will get an error that shows your session has expired (even though it hasn't). You can fix this by setting the page security on the page that is the modal window to "Page is Public". I have created a [demo application on apex.oracle.com](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/adptest/r/ej-demo/launch-session-expired-modal) to demonstrate.

[image: expired modal]